# How does this HTTP "redirect" work?

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-code-404

When I request this URL:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element
```

the server responds with a `404` (File not found) HTTP-response. However, a few moments later a **different URL** is loaded into the browser, namely:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-img-element.html#the-img-element
```

The server basically sends a **second HTTP-response** whose URL is different from the URL that was originally requested.

[image]

How is this "redirect" possible? The first HTTP-response was a `404`, not a `3xx`. Afaik, `404` responses do *not* trigger a second HTTP-request by the browser. So, does the server just push the second response without any request being made? If yes, why does the browser allow that?

---

**See for yourself:** Open the "Net" tab of Chrome's dev tools, and make sure that the "Preserve Log upon Navigation" flag is activated. Now, load the first URL (from above).

Comment: Uh, wait... Is JavaScript at work here? Well, that would be embarrassing `:)`

Comment: They _may_ use javascript, but it's not even needed: sending a `Refresh: 5;url=new_url.html` header would also work.

Comment: @Wrikken The `404` page that is returned here is generic, so they can't hard-code the specific new URL like that. What they do instead is, have a [huge JavaScript file with all the URL mappings](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fragment-links.js). This file is loaded by the `404` page, and then performs the corresponding redirect.

Comment: Yep, that's what they do here, just wanted to say there are more ways to get there. Be sure _not_ to follow their lead in this, and if you encounter this, do proper permanent redirects...

Comment: @Wrikken Actually, why return a `Refresh` header, when you can return  a `301` (Moved permanently) response `:)`. They decided to do it with JavaScript, but if they had decided to do it on the server-side, they would have implemented it via a `301` redirect, not via a `Refresh` header, I think.

Comment: A refresh header for your observed 'a ferw moment later' of course. Once again: I only sought to point out how _your observed behavior_ could be _replicated_ without javascript. Just an FYI, not a suggestion. I then proceeded to say that one _should_ do proper permanent redirects, which is exactly what you are telling me now like it's something new....

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my own question here.

The second HTTP-request is initiated by JavaScript code that is executed as part of the page that was returned by the `404` response. That page contains:

```
<body onload="fixBrokenLink(404)">
```

and then:

```
function fixBrokenLink(is404) {
    if (window.location.hash.length < 1 && !is404)
        return;

    var fragid = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    if (fragid && document.getElementById(fragid))
        return;

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'fragment-links.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

I love how I've asked the question, made a comment on it, and then answered it, all without any participation from anyone else. `:)`